# What is :: called and how to iterate inner object inside of map lambda function in java

Tags: java, lambda

I have see an answer like

`lisMap.map(Data::getId)).collect(Collectors.toList());`

I understand that it is getting value as getId inside map.
But I have 2 questrions here.

1)what is **::** called inside map?

2)if I have another object inside getId say getRealId so how will I write it? `Data::getId::getRealId?`

I'm new to java functions, I hope my question is understandable

Comment: `Data::getId` is a method reference to the `getId()` method inside class `Data`. It is basically equivalent to the lambda `(Data d) -> d.getId()`. I'm not 100% sure on your second question but I'm pretty sure the compiler can't resolve double method references. In that case you'd need to either use 2 calls to `map()`, e.g. `map(Data::getId).map(InnerClass::getRealId)` or use a normal lambda like `d->d.getId().getRealId()`.

Comment: @Thomas ok so I have another question after your ans.
How will I apply your ans in this case?
```Comparator.nullsLast(Data::getId)```?

Comment: You mean how to get the real id in this case? Use the lambda version. There are other options but this would be the easiest. If `getId()` could return `null` you can handle this inside the lambda.

Answer (score 0):

> what is :: called inside map?

[Method References](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html)

> if I have another object inside getId say getRealId so how will I write it?
> For example:

`lisMap.map(x -> x.getId().getRealId()).collect(Collectors.toList());`

/upd Depending on @Thomas's comment I should add that it is possible to rewrite this code as consecutive map chain.

For example:
`listMap.map(Data::getId).map(Id::getRealId).collect(Collectors.toList());`
Assuming that `Data::getId` returns `Id` object.

Comment: I want to select inner object with :: style i.e Method References like u mentioned

Comment: What's return type of method `Data::getId`?

Comment: @Arsegg that doesn't matter. You can't call anything on a method reference directly.

Comment: @Thomas, consecutive calls of map works well with that. Which is way better than lambda, imho.

Comment: Yes, that's true and now I see what you need the return type for :) - You could just _assume_ some type or at least you should mention the OP so they get your question.

Comment: @Arsegg return type of getId is Object of 
```RealId{
private String name;
priavteString detail;
getName(){
return this.name;}
setName(String name){
this.name =name;}
}```
something like this